# Application.js get cleaned up when building project with Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript

I have download the sample https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/typescript-angular and I try to get it working under a VS2013 Web Application empty template.
I add all the file of the sample, I launch the website by IIS, it works fine.

But when I build the project (without modifying anything) the only lines that remain are :

```
/// <reference path='_all.ts' />
/**
* The main TodoMVC app module.
*
* @type {angular.Module}
*/
var todos;
(function (todos) {
    'use strict';

    var todomvc = angular.module('todomvc', []).controller('todoCtrl', todos.TodoCtrl).directive('todoBlur', todos.todoBlur).directive('todoFocus', todos.todoFocus).service('todoStorage', todos.TodoStorage);
})(todos || (todos = {}));
```

When I try to run the website I have the following error :

```
http://localhost/WebAppTodoMvc/bower_components/angular/angular.js

0x800a139e - Erreur d’exécution JavaScript: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module todomvc due to
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'directiveFactory' is required
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to open an issue on the GitHub repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is meant to work with the `--out` compiler flag and you should use `_all.js` generated from `all.ts` https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/master/examples/typescript-angular/js/_all.ts

You can specify this as the *reference file* from your project properties.